# Appium: How can we reduce the time of sendkeys method

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am using sendkeys method in Appium android to enter text in textfield but it is taking large time to perform sendkeys action. So is there any method to reduce the time of sendkeys action.

```
WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
        emailField.click();
        emailField.sendKeys("rh@gmail.com");

        // Set text on password field
        WebElement passField = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
        passField.click();
        passField.sendKeys("123456");

        // Tap on Login button on Login screen
        driver.findElement(By.id("Sign_button")).click();
```

Comment: Do you using default android emulator or real device?

Comment: I am using real device like HTC.

Comment: Then it should not take long time to send keys. no method is available to do send keys faster... But mostly it works in good speed with any device.

Comment: I am using HTC ONE but it is taking more time in typing compare to other mobile action.

Comment: Can you please show you code? please put all your code in question.

Comment: I have added my code in question...

Comment: I think you are doing perfect , no mistake there..:)

Comment: Ok, i think it may be depend on type of device. thanks :)

Comment: According to this [link](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7085/regarding-setting-text-of-a-webelement-without-using-sendkeys-method) it's possible with JQuery with: `driver.executeScript("$('window>textfield').val('value');");` but I am not certain about how to select that particular element by id. Good luck!